# JSON.parse returning the undefined value

Tags: json, jsonp

`password.json` consists of

```
{    
    "passwd":"pavankumar",
     "name":"pavan"

};
```

tried with semicolon and without semicolon, both in Mozilla and Chrome

```
function ajax_post(){

  var hr=  new XMLHttpRequest();

  hr.open("GET", "password.json", true);

  hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json",true);

  hr.onreadystatechange = function(){

    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200){

       var data = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
       alert(data);   // At this stage the json file is displayed. correctly..
       var status = document.getElementById("status");
       status.innerHTML= data.name;     //returning the undefined value....     
    }
  }

  hr.send(null);
}
```

Comment: actually, if you do `alert(data)` you should see something like `[object Object]` so how do you know the json file is correctly?

Comment: see my json file at the top ...when ever i do alert(data) total json file is displayed.

Comment: What you see if you do `console.log(data)` in chrome?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

`hr.responseText` will be a string representing the JSON encoding of an object, so you do *not* want to `JSON.stringify` it; that will turn it into a JSON representation of a single string. Just `JSON.parse` it directly.

Comment: still same error when trying with JSON.parse , returning the undefined value

Comment: Edit the code in your question to reflect all the changes you made.